# ckeditor : limit the times an ordered and unordered list can nest

Tags: javascript, list, ckeditor, nested-lists

I have a project where I need to limit the number of times an ordered and unordered list can nest in CKEditor. I need to set this count to max 5 times nested.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have the same thing here now. Did you find any solution?